# Set Datagrid isRowSelectable property based on useListContext

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

In a React-Admin [Datagrid](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Datagrid.html) component, I want to set all of the list items to be individually selectable ([isRowSelectable](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Datagrid.html#isrowselectable)) based on all the rows in aggregate.

That is, all items should be selectable (if the status property is the same for all of them); OR all items should NOT be selectable (if the status property is NOT the same for all).

The code below does that, but has one problem. When I try to select all items using the checkbox at the top of the Datagrid, I get an error (`Invalid hook call ... handleSelectAll DatagridHeader.tsx:65`).

I *don't* get that error when I select the list items individually.

```
const checkAllStatuses = () => {
  const { data } = useListContext();
  const uniqueStatuses = [...new Set(data.map((item) => item.status))];
  return uniqueStatusStates.length === 1;
};

const EmployeeList = (props) => {
  return (
    <List title="Employees">
      <Datagrid isRowSelectable={checkAllStatuses}>
        ...
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
  );
};
```

How can I prevent the "Invalid hook call..." error when I select all the items collectively using the button at the top?

**Alternatively**, is there a way to disable or hide the "select all" checkbox in the Datagrid header - but only when the status property is not the same for all items?

Comment: Hooks can only be called inside other hooks or in the body of functional components, not in simple functions.

Comment: That's a good point. I'm actually a little stumped as to why the error only occurs when I select the checkbox in the Datagrid header.

Comment: Apparently in another case, the function call does not occur isRowSelectable.

Comment: The items do get disabled / enabled (without error) based on the result of my checkAllStatuses function. It's just the Datagrid header "select all" button that throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible implementation:

```
const DatagridCheck = () => {
  let checkAll = false
  const { data } = useListContext()

  if (data) {
    const uniqueStatuses = new Set(data.map((item) => item.status)) 
    checkAll = uniqueStatuses.size === 1
  }

  return (
    <Datagrid isRowSelectable={() => checkAll}>
      ...
    </Datagrid>
  )
}

const EmployeeList = (props) => {
  return (
    <List title="Employees">
      <DatagridCheck />
    </List>
  )
}
```

Comment: That seems to do it. And I don't get the error. Thanks, @MaxAlex!

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, you want to

1. Add a state to get your currently selected status
2. Create a function to overwrite the rows selection on the Datagrid (see https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/2000#issuecomment-840594240 to overwrite the selection)
3. Select everything else that has the same status when the user checks something
4. Also set the currently selected status when the user checks something
5. Use the currently selected status to also disable the checks on other rows

Which translates to:

```js
import { useRecordSelection } from 'react-admin' 

// step 2
const useSetSelectedRecords = (resource: string, ids: string[] | undefined) => {
  const [, { select }] = useRecordSelection(resource)
  useEffect(() => {
    ids && select(ids)
  }, [select, ids])
}

const EmployeeList = (props) => {

  const { data } = useListContext();
  const [currentStatus, setCurrentStatus ] = useState(undefined);// step 1

  return (
    <List title="Employees">
      <Datagrid isRowSelectable={(record) =>
        // step 5
        currentStatus && record.status === currentStatus
      }>
        ...
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
  );
};
```

And then call the code below (**step 3**) and the `setCurrentStatus` function (**step 4**) when the user interacts with the checkbox or as an effect for when the selected ids change.

```js
  useSetSelectedRecords(
    props.resource,
    data
      .filter(record => record.status === currentStatus)
      .map(record => record.id)
  )
```

And don't forget to call `setCurrentStatus(undefined)` when you remove all selections too to re-enable the row selection for all rows.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out. I think it may be little bit more involved than what I'm looking for. I really just want the records to either all be selectable (if the status property is the same for all of the items); or all be NOT selectable (if the status property is NOT the same for all).

Comment: FYI, I've updated my question a bit to add some additional progress I made.

Comment: I guess since what I'm trying to do doesn't seem to work, maybe I can try something like you're suggestion. It seems like that could solve my problem - though in a different way ... but that's giving me "resource is not defined".